# Unexpected Results When Working With Spatial Data In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, spatial-query

Consider the following SQL:

```
DECLARE @g1 AS GEOGRAPHY;
DECLARE @g2 AS GEOGRAPHY;
DECLARE @g3 AS GEOGRAPHY;

SET @g1 = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((-97.5 33.0, -97.5 34.0, -96.5 34.0, -96.5 33.0, -97.5 33.0))', 4326);
SET @g2 = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT (-97.5 33.5)', 4326);
SET @g3 = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT (-98.0 35.0)', 4326);

SELECT @g1.STIntersects(@g2);
SELECT @g1.STIntersects(@g3);
```

I would expect that the first result would be 1 (true) as the point (@g2) is on the line of the rectangle.  However, I would expect that the second result would be 0 (false) as the point (@p3) is nowhere near the region (@p1).  However, both results are 1 (true).

I feel as though there is something I am missing fundamentally.  If someone can explain, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This post helped me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054149/sql-server-2008-spatial-find-a-point-in-polygon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having not received any responses to this question, we posted the question on Reddit and received a response explaining the issue there.  This post can be viewed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/SQL/comments/8829cm/tsqlunexpected_results_when_working_with_spatial/).